# Modifying or defining a global variable from a classes __init__ method without the global keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm wondering if there's a way to modify/define a global variable from within a Python class's `.__init__` method without using the `global` keyword, so that the variable will be modified every time an instance of such class is created.
In example:

```
a = None

class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        global a
        a = 6
```

Can I do the same without using `global a`? (Alternatively the definition of global variable `a` from the `.__init__` would be acceptable.)

The context of the problem:
I'm creating a GUI app in which the user is faced with a line-edit and a button, both of them defined inside a class with a method for when the button is pressed. In case the button is pressed, the content of the line-edit is read and should be saved in a global variable, then the whole window automatically closes and the event loop stops. Also the UI's class will be imported to the file where the global variable will be, so the `global` keyword might not even work.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this, there may be a better way.

Comment: Why do you not want to use the `global` keyword? Purposefully obfuscating code is bad practice.

Comment: How about a class variable?

Comment: I edited the question with the description of this variables purpose in context.

Comment: This strongly feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Try to change your question to be about what it is you are trying to solve, and not the ***way*** you are trying to solve it

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test():
    a = 1
    def __init__(self):
        self.a += 6 # a += 6 modifies "global" class variable.

t = Test()
print(t.a)
#will print 7 (a=1 + 6)
```

So, instead of defining a global variable, you can define a class variable I did here.
print() statement will return 7 in this case as you sum default value of a = 1 and to 6 in the **init** method. In this case, variable a will belong to every instance of a class.

Comment: make sure to ask additional questions if the answer I provided did not cover what you 
really needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my problem is that the class will only be manually accessible upon definition. This means in your example that upon the time I request `t.a`, the `t` class won't exist.